# Group data with RXJava 2, add element to each group and output one list

Tags: java, sorting, rx-java2

I have an RXJava 2 observer that emits objects of type `somethingWithDate`. These objects have a property that contains a java date object as well as a `boolean isHeader`.

What I need to do with these objects is:

1. Group them by month and year (all dates in January of 2017, all dates in January of 2016, all dates in February 2016, ...)
2. Add a header (also a `somethingWithDate`) at the start of the group
3. Sort groups in regard to each other (by date, sorting inside the groups would be nice too but not needed, the header needs to stay at first position in each group)
4. Merged(?) all elements from all groups back into one list of elements `single<List<somethingWithDate>>`

Here is an example (all objects of type `somethingWithDate`, but I will only display the important properties here to make it more readable):

Input Data:

```
1.1.2017, 2.1.2017, 1.1.2016, 8.8.2017
```

Result:

```
header, 1.1.2016, header, 1.1.2017, 2.1.2017, header, 8.8.2017
```

I know 1. can be achieved by using `groupBy()`. I haven't found a way to do 2 though. I also know there is a `toList()` and `toSortedList()` to maybe use for 3. and 4. but I am unsure how that works with the groups from the `groupBy()` and how I can collect them back in one list.

Pseudocode:

```
inputListObserver
    .groupBy(obj.date.year + obj.date.month)
    .map(group -> group.addAtBeginning(headerElement))
    .sortBy(groupKey)
    .mergeToList()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found an answer. Using flatmap (thanks for the idea @masps)seems to do the trick. Here is the pseudo code:

```
.groupBy(makeKeyFromMonthAndYear()) // groups everything in months
.sorted(byGroupKey) // sorts the groups
.flatMap( // collect all groups back into one
   .startsWith(generateHeaderElement()) // add a header for each group
   .sorted() // optional, sort the values in a month
)
.toList() // output a Single<List<somethingWithDate>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `ConnectableObservable` to share the emissions of the initial stream. 
With this pseudocode you have 3 sorted streams by year with a header.

```
ConnectableSoureObservable = sourceObservable.publish()      
Observable.Concat(
                    ConnectableSoureObservable
                                        .filter(Year2015)
                                        .collectInto(newList<somethingWithDate>(initialValue))
                                        .toSortedList()
                                        .flatMapIterable(),
                    ConnectableSoureObservable
                                        .filter(Year2016)
                                        .collectInto(newList<somethingWithDate>(initialValue))
                                        .toSortedList()
                                        .flatMapIterable(),
                    ConnectableSoureObservable
                                        .filter(Year2017)
                                        .collectInto(newList<somethingWithDate>(initialValue))
                                        .toSortedList()
                                        .flatmapIterable())
                    ...
 ConnectableSoureObservable.connect()
```

Comment: This has the distinct disadvantage that I would have to do this for every month for every year by hand. So not very elegant. Still thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad that I helped. Concat accepts an Iterable as well. You don't have to do it by hand.