# Android Jetpack Pagination using Fragment: Adapter not receiving callback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination, dagger-2

I am following the approach described in [this](https://leaks.wanari.com/2018/07/30/android-jetpack-paging-firebase/) post (the corresponding repository can be found [here](https://github.com/TeamWanari/android-pagination-example))
to use the Paging library in order to partially load data from my Firestore database.
Instead of making use of a different activity (as is done in the original post), I put the code in a Fragment.

In my DataSource, the `loadInitial` function gets called in which we subscribe to the results.
Once the results are available, calling `callback.onResult` with as argument the newly retrieved data does not reach the adapter. After stepping in and through the `callback.onResult` function, the following exception occurs in the `onNext` method:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: callback.onResult already called, cannot call again.
```

However, if I press the back button, login again, the invocation of `callback.Onresult` **does** reach the adapter.

Initially, this made me believe that I was doing something wrong that was related to the lifecycle of the activity/fragment, however changing the place at which the adapter is initialized with the activity context did not change the result.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763454/6409815) post also mentions something about loading a fragment twice in order to get things working, which might explain the observed result when pressing the back button and returning.

**EDIT: Added more relevant (updated) code**

**EDIT 2: Added extra Dagger annotations and refactored code in `WorkManager` to make use of RxJava2**

**EDIT 3: I completely stripped all of the Dagger 2 usages and now the code works, so the problem is Dagger related**

**EDIT 4: Problem solved, see my post below**

The relevant code is as follows:

**Fragment**

```
class TradeRequestFragment : Fragment() {

    private val auth: FirebaseAuth by lazy { FirebaseAuth.getInstance() }
    private lateinit var rootView: View

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trade_requests, container, false)
        return rootView
    }

    private fun initAdapter() {
        // Setup the RecyclerView for the User's trade requests.
        // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
        val tradeRequestRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.trade_requests_recycler_view)
        // 2. set LayoutManager
        tradeRequestRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
        val tradeRequestAdapter = TradeRequestAdapter(activity?.applicationContext)

        // Dagger 2 injection
        val component = DaggerTradeRequestFragment_TradeRequestComponent.builder().tradeRequestModule(TradeRequestModule()).build()
        val tradeRequestViewModel = TradeRequestViewModel(component.getTradeRequestDataProvider())

        // 3. Set Adapter
        tradeRequestRecyclerView.adapter = tradeRequestAdapter
        // 4. Set the item animator
        tradeRequestRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity?.applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
        tradeRequestViewModel.getTradeRequests()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer(tradeRequestAdapter::submitList))
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        initAdapter()
    }

    @Module
    inner class TradeRequestModule {

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideDataSource(): TradeRequestsDataSource {
            return TradeRequestsDataSource(auth.currentUser?.uid
                    ?: "")
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideUserId(): String {
            return auth.currentUser?.uid ?: ""
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = [TradeRequestModule::class])
    interface TradeRequestComponent {
        fun getTradeRequestDataProvider(): TradeRequestDataProvider
    }
}
```

**TradeRequestManager**

```
class TradeRequestManager private constructor(userID: String) {
    companion object : Utils.Singleton<TradeRequestManager, String>(::TradeRequestManager)


    private val TRADE_REQUEST_ROUTE = "tradeRequests"
    private val userIDKey = "userId"
    private val userTradeRequestsAdapterInvalidation = PublishSubject.create<Any>()
    private val database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val databaseRef: Query? by lazy {
        try {
            database.collection(TRADE_REQUEST_ROUTE).whereEqualTo(userIDKey, userID)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(this.TAG(), "Could not retrieve the user's trade requests", e.cause)
            null
        }
    }

    private val tradeRequestBuilder: Moshi by lazy {
        Moshi.Builder()
                .add(ZonedDateTime::class.java, ZonedDateTimeAdapter())
                .add(CurrencyUnit::class.java, CurrencyUnitAdapter())
                .add(Money::class.java, JodaMoneyAdapter())
                .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                .build()
    }
    private val tradeRequestAdapter: JsonAdapter<TradeRequest> by lazy { tradeRequestBuilder.adapter(TradeRequest::class.java) }


    // TODO see [here][https://leaks.wanari.com/2018/07/30/android-jetpack-paging-firebase]
    init {
        databaseRef?.addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
            override fun onEvent(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e(this.TAG(), "listener:error", e)
                    return
                }
                if (snapshot == null) {
                    return
                }
                for (dc in snapshot.documentChanges) {
                    when (dc.type) {
                        DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> userTradeRequestsAdapterInvalidation.onNext(true)
                        DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> userTradeRequestsAdapterInvalidation.onNext(true)
                        DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> userTradeRequestsAdapterInvalidation.onNext(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    fun getUserTradeRequestsChangeSubject(): PublishSubject<Any>? {
        return userTradeRequestsAdapterInvalidation
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420829/group-data-with-rxjava-2-add-element-to-each-group-and-output-one-list
    fun getTradeRequests(count: Int): Single<List<TradeRequest?>> {
        if (databaseRef == null) {
            return Observable.empty<List<TradeRequest?>>().singleOrError()
        }
        // By default, we order by 'creationDate' descending
        // If the field by which we order does not exists, no results are returned
        return RxFirestore.observeQueryRef(databaseRef!!.orderBy("creationDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(count.toLong()))
                .firstElement()
                .toSingle()
                .flattenAsObservable { list -> list.documents }
                .flatMap { doc -> Observable.just(doc.data as? Map<String, String>) }
                .map { json -> tryOrNull { tradeRequestAdapter.fromJsonValue(json) } }
                .filter { tradeRequest -> tradeRequest != null }
                .toList()
    }

    fun getTradeRequestsAfter(key: String, value: String, count: Int, order: Query.Direction): Single<Pair<List<TradeRequest?>, String>> {
        if (databaseRef == null) {
            return Observable.empty<Pair<List<TradeRequest?>, String>>().singleOrError()
        }
        val result = RxFirestore.observeQueryRef(databaseRef!!.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(key, value).limit(count.toLong()).orderBy(key, order))
                .firstElement()
                .toSingle()
                .flattenAsObservable { list -> list.documents }
                .flatMap { doc -> Observable.just(doc.data as? Map<String, String>) }
                .map { json -> tryOrNull { tradeRequestAdapter.fromJsonValue(json) } }
                .filter { tradeRequest -> tradeRequest != null }
                .toList()

        val tradeRequests = result.blockingGet()

        // FIXME determine next filter value
        var newFilterValue = ""
        if (tradeRequests.size == count) {
            // Either the number of elements is capped or exactly "count" elements matched
            newFilterValue = ""
        }
        // END FIXME
        return Observable.just(Pair(tradeRequests, newFilterValue)).singleOrError()
    }

    fun getTradeRequestsBefore(key: String, value: String, count: Int, order: Query.Direction): Single<Pair<List<TradeRequest?>, String>> {
        if (databaseRef == null) {
            return Observable.empty<Pair<List<TradeRequest?>, String>>().singleOrError()
        }
        val result = RxFirestore.observeQueryRef(databaseRef!!.whereLessThan(key, value).limit(count.toLong()).orderBy(key, order))
                .firstElement()
                .toSingle()
                .flattenAsObservable { list -> list.documents }
                .flatMap { doc -> Observable.just(doc.data as? Map<String, String>) }
                .map { json -> tryOrNull { tradeRequestAdapter.fromJsonValue(json) } }
                .filter { tradeRequest -> tradeRequest != null }
                .toList()

        val tradeRequests = result.blockingGet()

        // FIXME determine next filter value
        var newFilterValue = ""
        if (tradeRequests.size == count) {
            // Either the number of elements is capped or exactly "count" elements matched
            newFilterValue = ""
        }
        // END FIXME
        return Observable.just(Pair(tradeRequests, newFilterValue)).singleOrError()
    }
```

**DataSource**

```
class TradeRequestsDataSource @Inject constructor(var userId: String, var filter: Data) : ItemKeyedDataSource<String, TradeRequest>() {


    private var filterKey: String
    private var filterValue: String
    private var filterOrder: Query.Direction
    private var userTradeRequestsManager: TradeRequestManager = TradeRequestManager.getInstance(userId)

    init {
        userTradeRequestsManager.getUserTradeRequestsChangeSubject()?.observeOn(Schedulers.io())?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())?.subscribe {
            invalidate()
        }

        filterKey = filter.getString("filterKey") ?: ""
        filterValue = filter.getString("filterValue") ?: ""
        filterOrder = try {
            Query.Direction.valueOf(filter.getString("filterOrder") ?: "")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Query.Direction.DESCENDING
        }
    }

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<TradeRequest>) {
        Log.i(this.TAG(), "Loading the initial items in the RecyclerView")
        userTradeRequestsManager.getTradeRequests(params.requestedLoadSize).singleElement().subscribe({ tradeRequests ->
            Log.i(this.TAG(), "We received the callback")
            callback.onResult(tradeRequests)
        }, {})
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<String>, callback: LoadCallback<TradeRequest>) {
        userTradeRequestsManager.getTradeRequestsAfter(params.key, this.filterValue, params.requestedLoadSize, this.filterOrder).singleElement().subscribe({
            this.filterValue = it.second
            callback.onResult(it.first)
        }, {})
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<String>, callback: LoadCallback<TradeRequest>) {
        userTradeRequestsManager.getTradeRequestsBefore(params.key, this.filterValue, params.requestedLoadSize, this.filterOrder).singleElement().subscribe({
            this.filterValue = it.second
            callback.onResult(it.first)
        }, {})
    }

    override fun getKey(item: TradeRequest): String {
        return filterKey
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
class TradeRequestAdapter(val context: Context?) : PagedListAdapter<TradeRequest, TradeRequestAdapter.TradeRequestViewHolder>(
        object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TradeRequest>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TradeRequest, newItem: TradeRequest): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TradeRequest, newItem: TradeRequest): Boolean {
                return oldItem.amount == newItem.amount &&
                        oldItem.baseCurrency == newItem.baseCurrency &&
                        oldItem.counterCurrency == newItem.counterCurrency &&
                        oldItem.creationDate == newItem.creationDate &&
                        oldItem.userId == newItem.userId


            }
        }) {


    private lateinit var mInflater: LayoutInflater

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TradeRequestViewHolder {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trade_request_item, parent, false)
        return TradeRequestViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TradeRequestViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val tradeRequest = getItem(position)
        holder.tradeRequestBaseCurrency.text = tradeRequest?.baseCurrency.toString()
        holder.tradeRequestCounterCurrency.text = tradeRequest?.counterCurrency.toString()
        holder.tradeRequestAmount.text = tradeRequest?.amount.toString()
    }


    // Placeholder class for displaying a single TradeRequest
    class TradeRequestViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tradeRequestBaseCurrency: TextView = itemView.trade_request_item_from_currency
        var tradeRequestCounterCurrency: TextView = itemView.trade_request_item_to_currency
        var tradeRequestAmount: TextView = itemView.trade_request_item_amount
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably `TradeRequestManager` exposes `Flowable/Observable` instead of `Single` so you're creating subscriptions that never die.

Comment: You are right, the __getTradeRequests function__ shows my implementation of the ``TradeRequestManager.getTradeRequests``, which indeed returns an Observable. I'm quite new to RXJava, but I found the `toSingle` method which can transform from the `Observable` to the `Single` world. However I cannot apply it to the `PublishSubject`

Comment: ok, but overall the source of the bug is `TradeRequestManager` being misused, but we do not see its code.

Comment: I have added `TradeRequestManager` code and changed the subscriptions in `TradeRequestsDataSource` to make them observe `Single` using the `singleElement()` method. Assuming this is done correctly, I am still observing the same behavior

Comment: I do not understand why your `TradeRequestsDataSource` is not a `PositionalDataSource` that wraps the FireStore Query that supports `limit/offset` using `startAt` + `limit`. So what you'd need to do is mirror [what `Room` does](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/706a2o/paging_library_preview/do4h0z0/), although there is a chance that observing changes made to the FULL collection but only showing a SUBSET of the collection is tricky with Firestore.

Comment: Maybe check what [FirestorePagingAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/1e86767333d78ec910b3ce8802daff8935944daa/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/paging/FirestorePagingAdapter.java) does? Either way, firestore subscriptions aren't one-off, and if you're using Firestore you should generally try to use their real-time capabilities as it results in much easier code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I want the user to be able to select a filter (e.g. date, amount, etc..) and then let the `Usermanager` retrieve the values with respect to these filters. 
In this case, I imagined that a key would be the filter that is currently applied (e.g. `creationDate`) and a value would indicate min/max value of the elements that will come after the user scrolls up/down.
This enables me to create queries with small results in the `loadBefore` and `loadAfter` methods.
Regardless of whether this is a good approach or not, it is still weird that my callback is not received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the dependy injection done in the `DataFactory`.
The original code was as follows:

```
@Singleton
class AnimalDataFactory @Inject constructor(): DataSource.Factory<String, Animal>() {


    private var datasourceLiveData = MutableLiveData<AnimalDataSource>()


    override fun create(): AnimalDataSource {
        // CORRECT: DataSource MUST be initialized here, otherwise items will not show up on initial activity/fragment launch
        val dataSource = AnimalDataSource()
        datasourceLiveData.postValue(dataSource)
        return dataSource
    }
}
```

while I changed this to

```
@Singleton
class AnimalDataFactory @Inject constructor(var dataSource: AnimalDataSourc): DataSource.Factory<String, Animal>() {


    private var datasourceLiveData = MutableLiveData<AnimalDataSource>()


    override fun create(): AnimalDataSource {
        // WRONG
        datasourceLiveData.postValue(dataSource)
        return dataSource
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure why this solves the problem, but it works.